# angular-charts.js wont properly update with new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

the chart HTML

```
<!-- the data-component is a block where theres a chart
     and a table. Since the table doesn't ever have issues,
     it always displays the real async data...
     but because the chart wont render my async data,
     I start it off with some fake data so I can see it -->
<div class="data-component">
  <canvas id="bar"
    class="chart chart-bar"
    data="data"
    labels="labels">

  <table>
   ... the real data ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Initial (fake) data:

```
$scope.data= [
    [1,2,3]
];
$scope.labels = [1,2,3];
$scope.series = ['field1'];
```

Results in this:
[image]

data update:

```
$http.get( _url )
  .success(function(distribution) {
  $scope.loading = false;
  console.log(distribution);
  var seriesData = [];
  var labels = [];
  for(var i in distribution)
  {
    var step = distribution[i];

    //This is the data returned
    //[{"segment":null,"count":308,"percentage":0.77},
    //{"segment":1,"count":16346,"percentage":40.71},
    //{"segment":2,"count":13186,"percentage":32.84},    
    //{"segment":3,"count":10309,"percentage":25.68}]

    seriesData.push(step.count);
    labels.push(step.segment || "null");
  }

  $scope.distribution = distribution;

  $scope.data = [seriesData];
  $scope.labels = labels;
  $scope.series = ["Field2"];

})
.error(function() {});
```

results in this:
[image]

Does anyone know why async updates of the data causes it to render nothing at all?

Comment: if you could provide a fiddle it would be very helpful

Comment: actually, I can't do that right now, i'd have to create a mini architecture to run in fiddle since the application is big and complex, and I'm about to leave my house, so I dont have time to do that. sorry